# Yii2 - Avoid sending session cookie on external request

Tags: cookies, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Is it possible to **avoid** sending a user session cookie when receiving a request from an external server on a specific action?

I have and endpoint inside a normal frontend controller and I would like not to send the session cookie "advanced_frontend" on that action with the response, since it is popping up in a third party site.

I copy below one of the response headers from that suspicious request:

```
set-cookie: advanced-frontend=XXXX;path=/;httpOnly
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 7.3+ and Yii 2.0.21+ you can set [sameSite](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-sessions-cookies#samesite) parameter for your cookies with `Strict` value (`components` > `session` > `cookieParams`).

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. No I'm not currently using php 7.3 nor Yii 2.0.21+ although I'm in the process of upgrading. I would like to know, if possible, to avoid sending that cookie at all on that request.